# what's the difference between javascript PACKED and PACKER

Tags: javascript, compression, packed

I found two difference way to pack javascript file, there's packed and packer.
the encode js file after packed looks like this:

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){..});
```

and

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){...});
```

what is the difference of two kinds?
I know the way to pack in second type (packer), but don't know how to pack in first way (packed)
anyone can help me?

Comment: Looks like both have the same developer. `r` must be better than `d` since the current packing tool in the site is "packer".

Comment: tks @JosephtheDreamer, I tried to unpacked packed file with http://www.strictly-software.com/unpacker, and then pack again this file with http://dean.edwards.name/packer/. but this file didn't work, what's wrong with it?

Comment: if you want to unpack it, just change the first word, "eval", to "String"

Comment: I need to unpacked packed file and edit some code in it, then packed this file again in the original way. That's my problem

Comment: Works for me, don't know why it doesn't for you. Is your JS valid?

Comment: Why does the code need to be "packed" in the original way?